# How to align objects to centre of page?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have tried aligning the objects in my webpage with the following CSS but the [objects were not positioned at the centre](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/4892yp0se30z5g7/Capture.PNG?dl=1). What should I do?

```
left:50%;
margin-left:-25%;
```

Comment: your positioning is looking really bad, you need to share out some markup here or simply use `margin: auto` if you want to align center..

Answer (score 9):

Can you try this please? It works fine

Works on : Internet Explorer - Google Chrome - Safari - Mozilla

```
<!-- Div content -->
<div style="margin:0 auto;text-align:center">

      <!-- Div align in the middle -->
      <div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align:center">
            <p>Hello my text is in the middle :-) </p>
      </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Question is about objects, not text.  A more helpful example would have used three or 4 objects centered on a page, while arranged in specific relation to each other.

Answer (score 2):

The objects parent element (their container) must be set to position:relative

The objects themselves should be set to position:absolute, left:50%, margin-left negative value in pixels which is half the value of the object.

Alternatively you could also try simply setting the parent element to have text-align:center and give the objects themselves "margin:0 auto;"